# lstlisting : how to remove unwanted header?

Tags: listings, filecontents

I have a listing that I use to display some code.
I use `filecontents` to specify the content and `lstinputlisting` to display it.

The resulting pdf looks ok (used PDFLaTex), but above my code I get:

```
%% LaTeX2e file ‘[]’
%% generated by the ‘filecontents’ environment
%% from source ‘[]’ on 2016/12/29.
```

any way to get ride of this ?

Comment: Use `filecontents*` instead of `filecontents`.

Comment: Or tell listings to ignore the first lines with the `firstline` option.

Comment: @PeterGrill but that would force it to span two columns ? (I use a two columns layout)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer works :) would be happy to valid the answer, if provided as such

Comment: What do you mean about spanning two columns? The `filecontents` environment only writes its content to an external file, there is nothing that can span two columns. The starred version of the environment writes a file without the header you mention.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Peter in his comment you can avoid to get the preamble in a file generated by a filecontents environment by using the starred version of filecontents. If this is not possible you can suppress the starting lines with the `firstline` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{mylisting1.txt}
bla
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mylisting2.txt}
bla
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=5,frame=single]{mylisting1.txt}

\lstinputlisting[frame=single]{mylisting2.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]